# Nothing is printing in the Intellij with Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Absolutelynew to Intellij, so I created a new project, then a new scala object in the the src file. I tried to run it but nothing really happens. I'm fairly sure it has to do with the run configurations but I've tried ScalaTest, ScalaConsole, and ScalaScript. I feel it has to do with these but I don't know how to get the run configurations to work so I can see output in the console. All I'm trying is the hello world program so It's nothing programming wise.

Comment: You sure its an scala `object`. This should work: `object Name{ def main(args:Array[String]){ println("hey")}}`

Comment: Yes I get how to actually code it, It's a problem I'm having with the IDE

Comment: I'd recommend you to use activator Ui in order to create new scala template and import it into the IDE

Comment: So you select that file in the project browser and select 'Run <object-name>'? What happens next? Perhaps you get a compile error you are not aware of.